# Animate Object along path while scrolling. (GSAP, MotionPath, ScrollTrigger)

Tags: javascript, svg, scrolltrigger

I am trying to animate a dot along an svg path. While scrolling the dot should move along the line and you should scrolldown in the viewport.
How do I do this?

[It should look like this, but only vertical scroll](https://codepen.io/neeraj121/pen/qBNYxWv)

Thank you in advance, i'm new to this so i think i need a lot of help.

```html
<p class="codepen" data-height="300" data-default-tab="html,result" data-slug-hash="qBNYxWv" data-user="neeraj121" style="height: 300px; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; border: 2px solid; margin: 1em 0; padding: 1em;">
  <span>See the Pen <a href="https://codepen.io/neeraj121/pen/qBNYxWv">
  ScrollTrigger with MotionPath</a> by Neeraj (<a href="https://codepen.io/neeraj121">@neeraj121</a>)
  on <a href="https://codepen.io">CodePen</a>.</span>
</p>
<script async src="https://cpwebassets.codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js"></script>
```

Comment: Break up your learningpath in smaller segments: (1) Learn to draw with SVG (2) Learn to animate SVG (3) Learn to handle Scroll animations